# Linking OpenCV with cmake . Adding the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't work

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to create the script to compile and run as mentioned by [emscirpten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html).

This is the command I wish to create a cmake file for.

```
./emcc -std=c++11 -O3 -I.. ~/DLIB/dlib-19.4/dlib/all/source.cpp  -I/home/akshay/DLIB/dlib-19.4 -I/usr/include/X11/ -lpthread -lX11 -lopencv_imgcodecs  -o webca.js  ~/DLIB/dlib-19.4/examples/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp -ldlib  `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

So far I have come up with this. This is my CMAKELists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(DLIB)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_INIT "Release")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "emcc")
    endif ()

if(NOT DEFINED OpenCV_PREFIX)
  set(OpenCV_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
  endif()

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build.emscripten)

set(DLIB_SRC "/home/akshay/DLIB/dlib-19.4/examples/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp")
add_library(DLIB_static ${DLIB_SRC})
set(OpenCV_PREFIX /usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake)

include_directories(/usr/include/X11 /home/akshay/DLIB/dlib-19.4 /home/akshay/DLIB/dlib-19.4/dlib/all/source.cpp)

set_target_properties(DLIB_static PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 --preload-file assets --bind")
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED  
    PATHS ${OpenCV_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/
    ${OpenCV_PREFIX}/share/OpenCV/
      NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(OpenCV REQUIRED     PATHS ${OpenCV_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/
    ${OpenCV_PREFIX}/share/OpenCV/
      NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -O3 -lpthread -lX11 -lopencv_imgcodecs -ldlib `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`")

#file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE_HDR src/.h)
#file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE_SRC src/.cpp)

add_definitions("-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 --preload-file ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets --bind")
add_executable(DLIB /home/akshay/DLIB/dlib-19.4/examples/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp)
```

When I run this command :`cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/akshay/Downloads/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.16/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake . && make`

It gives me an error like so :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

It seems to not be able to find the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or that I am not setting it correctly.

I have just started fiddling around with CMAKE since yesterday. I may have very little clue about what I have done. Have tried some of the other SO answers as well.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: One problem I've noticed with your CMake file above. You are setting OpenCV_PREFIX to the actual config file but using it in your find_package as a PATH. If you remove the OpenCVConfig.cmake portion of that, CMake should find the package. You also don't need the find_library call. Find_package will handle the libraries through the OpenCV config. Fix that and possibly follow elvis' advice below and you don't need the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: @StAlphonzo Oh yeah , I thought I had marked his answer as accepted. I think there was some internet problem.

Comment: No worries, I was only adding support to the real answer because you have issues in your CMakeLists file. I figure that was worth addressing as well to help you (and others) out. Also, it's possible that fixing your CMake file will remove the need for setting any options on the command line though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to set the `OpenCV_DIR` to the path where `OpenCV` is installed, for example:

```
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/share/OpenCV ..
```

Comment: what **exactly** means "where OpenCV is installed"?  I tried this by putting the path to where the lib folder is but it did not work